# Hiding form field borders on app version of Acrobat Reader

Tags: javascript, forms, border, acrobat

I am working with an interactive PDF that has editable form fields.

I am aware of how to hide the form field borders in preferences when using the interactive PDF on a desktop/laptop but can't seem to figure out how to hide the same borders via the app version of Acrobat Reader.

Is there a piece of javascript code that could help me with this? Have you encountered the same issue?

Any and all work arounds appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean "on mobile devices" by "app version", you may be out of luck with the Adobe product.

On iOS use (and have your users use) a better PDF viewer, such as PDFExpert by Readdle.